# Compute predictive power variable on stock returns

Tags: predictive-models, spss

I have a self made dataset with 40 stocks listed with following information in a range for 1 month:
- closing price stock
- sentiment score

e.g.

01-01-2018 - closing price - sentiment score for that day
02-01-2018 - ....

I want to analyze if the sentiment score has some predictive power to the stock price (so closing price)

What's the best way to do this? I already did a pearson and spearman correlation.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing data, but regression comes to  mind. // Remembering that "Past results do not ensure future performance.""

Comment: @BruceET I edited an example to my question. regression? Lineair or logistic? And only with the closing price as "output" and the sentiment score as variable?

Comment: You'd need a time series analysis approach, not a regular regression. Check out the time series and forecasting tags here.

Comment: @mkt could a Kalman filter be used?